# How to Resolve null method error in groovy and object casting

Tags: groovy, geb

```
import java.io.IOException;
import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

public class Signin {
    def browser = new Browser()
    def driver

    public launch() throws IOException {
        browser.driver = new FirefoxDriver()
        browser.go"http://www.gmail.com/"
        sleep(1000)
        println "First Class completed"
    } 
}
```

Main class

```
import geb.Browser;
import java.io.IOException;
import Signin

class Main {

    static main(args) throws IOException {
        Signin first =new Signin()
        first.launch()
        sleep(1000)
        Search third =new Search()
        third.search()
    }   
}

import geb.Browser
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByXPath;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import geb.*
import Signin

class Search extends Signin {
    def elementToClick

    void search() throws IOException {  
        sleep(1000)
        println"search class"
        wait(1000)
        WebElement myaccount =browser.$("a", title: "my account")
        myaccount.click() 
//        WebElement elementToClick = driver.$("a", title:"searchTerm");
//        elementToClick.click()  
        browser.$("input", id:"searchTerm").value("abi")
        sleep(1000)
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pay-now\"]")).click();
        println "Search class completed"  
    }  
}
```

output::

```
First Class completed

search class

Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'geb.navigator.    EmptyNavigator' to class 'org.openqa.selenium.WebElement'
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' to     class 'org.openqa.selenium.WebElement'
    at Search.search(Search.groovy:22)
    at Search$search.call(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.groovy:22)
```

please help me to resolve the error

Note: if i enable  WebElement elementToClick = driver.$("a", title:"searchTerm");
     elementToClick.click() this line 
it throws the error $() null method

Comment: Change `WebElement` to `def`. I suspect your problem is that a link with that title doesn't exist on the page

Comment: click() method is getting error :  Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.click() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String) values: [[title:my account], a]
Possible solutions: click(), click(java.lang.Class), click(java.util.List), wait(), last(), size()

Comment: Doesn't a EmptyNavigator mean the element does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, try using `def` instead of `WebElement`. If you must give type to the variable, try using `Navigator`. From your original post, Geb wasn't able to return the content `a` link with attribute `title` having value `my account`. So, an `EmptyNavigator` is returned, which is not and does not extend `WebElement`.

The webdriver used does not know of a $() method. This is a method Geb implements in its page content handling. The `Browser` object is aware of page content.

Your post in the comments looks like you tried to pass in arguments to `click()`, none of which were valid. Once you successfully retrieve page content, you'll be able to use `click()` on that content as you attempted in the initial post.

tim_yates suggested this in the comments, but I also agree that it does not look like you're correctly getting the content on the page.

Please refer to http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#full_examples for working examples. The link will also take you to the Geb documentation.